# Difference between InnerHTML and InnerText property of ASP.Net controls?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

While using ASP.NET controls, for example

```
<h1 id="header" runat="server">text</h1>
```

if we want to change the text of the header we can do it probably by two properties `InnerHTML` and `InnerText`. I want to know what is the basic difference between the two properties?

Comment: @HighCore More or less. See my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`InnerHtml` lets you enter HTML code directly, `InnerText` formats everything you put in there for it to be taken as plain text.

For example, if you were to enter this in both properties: `Hello <b>world</b>`

This is what you would get with InnerHTML:

> Hello **world**

That is, exactly the same HTML you entered.

Instead, if you use `InnerText`, you get this:

> `Hello <b>world</b>`

And the resulting HTML would be `Hello &lt;b&gt;world&lt;/b&gt;`

Comment: Innertext in that case would return `Hello world` as it determines the contents ignoring tags

Comment: @megawac Are you absolutely sure? As I understand it, InnerText calls HtmlEncode. I can't test it right now, though :/

Comment: @megawac Like I said to andleer, there is a difference between InnerText in ASP.Net and innerText in javascript. The post you're referencing is talking about JS.

Comment: nevermind looks like you were correct - too much js since I worked with asp

Comment: @megawac No problem, it's been a while since I did anything in ASP.Net too. I only recalled that InnerText used HtmlEncode when you set it (and after that last comment, I noticed Tim Medora's answer in this question actually has the decompiled source of the property :P I find it pretty interesting that InnerHTML actually creates the objects for anything it finds there!)

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, go to the source (or decompile):

In `HtmlContainerControl`:

```
public virtual string InnerText
{
    get
    {
        return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(this.InnerHtml);
    }
    set
    {
        this.InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value);
    }
}

public virtual string InnerHtml
{
    get
    {
        if (base.IsLiteralContent())
        {
            return ((LiteralControl)this.Controls[0]).Text;
        }
        if (this.HasControls() && this.Controls.Count == 1 && this.Controls[0] is DataBoundLiteralControl)
        {
            return ((DataBoundLiteralControl)this.Controls[0]).Text;
        }
        if (this.Controls.Count == 0)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        throw new HttpException(SR.GetString("Inner_Content_not_literal", new object[]
        {
            this.ID
        }));
    }
    set
    {
        this.Controls.Clear();
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(value));
        this.ViewState["innerhtml"] = value;
    }
}
```

Both properties ultimately use `InnerHtml`, but setting `InnerText` HTML encodes the value so that it will be displayed literally in the browser versus interpreted as markup.

Remember that assigning to `InnerHtml` will not encode the value, and thus any user-driven content should be sanitized prior to assignment.

This also emphasizes how important it is to be mindful of view state (note the last line of `InnerHtml`'s setter; everything ends up in view state whether or not you need it).

Answer (score 0):

InnerHtml allows to insert html formated text within an HTML container, while InnerText only allows plain text (if I remember correctly this property trims any type of html you try to put in it)

1. InnerHtml. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innerhtml.aspx
2. InnerText. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innertext.aspx