# Adding carriage returns to Html control eg) div or span

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, carriage-return

This code ASPX file:

```
        Relates to:
        <div ID="relatedMeasures" runat="server"></div>
        <br />
```

Code behind loops through items and appends to a string...

```
  foreach (int id in mcsMeasuresSelected)
  {
     if (mcs.Id == id)
        {
          // Add to selected
           mcsSelectedMeasures.Add(mcs);
           output += mcs.Measure + Environment.NewLine;
        }
  }
relatedMeasures.InnerText = output;
```

Then the output HTML has no line breaks.

```
 Relates to:
<div id="MainContent_extScope1_relatedMeasures">CPS: Gas Boiler Solid Fuel Boiler Electric Storage Heater </div>
```

I have also attempted using a span tag instead of div tag and an asp label and also adding "< br / >" or "<br/>" instead of Environment.NewLine

Comment: Do I need to HTMLencode the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<br/>` instead of Environment.NewLine. Like this.

`output += mcs.Measure + "<br />";`

and use InnerHTML , like following.

`relatedMeasures.InnerHtml = output;`

This is the difference between them - [Difference between InnerHTML and InnerText property of ASP.Net controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413642/difference-between-innerhtml-and-innertext-property-of-asp-net-controls)